# Removing PHP object if less than x comments or if an other object is enabled

Tags: php, pagination

I have two PHP objects

`if(function_exists('wp_commentnavi')) { wp_commentnavi(); }`

which is the comment pagination and

`if(function_exists('wp_commentnavi_all_comments_link')) { wp_commentnavi_all_comments_link(); }`

which is the all comments link.

I would like the second, all the comments link, to be only displayed if

a) there are more than x comments OR

b) if the comment pagination isn't displayed neither should the all comments link.

Essentially I want to say display all comments link if there are more than x comments, if not don't display all comments link.

OR - If pagination is required (i.e. the first object is active) then display all comments link.

Anyone know the code required to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (wp_count_comments() < $X && function_exists('wp_commentnavi_all_comments_link')) {

    // Do something
}
```

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes that's the theory I am looking for. That precise code however causes the website to fail, I copied it in and changed the x to 10, is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, `$x` is the number of comments you want to display. What failed exactly? I haven't tested my code.

Comment: Well I replaced 
`<?php if(function_exists('wp_commentnavi_all_comments_link')) { wp_commentnavi_all_comments_link(); } ?>` 
with  
`<?php if (wp_count_comments() < $5 && function_exists('wp_commentnavi_all_comments_link')) {

    // Do something
} ?>`
and everything but the header doesn't show. No idea why as I have very limited knowledge of php but some kind of critical error!

Comment: `< 5` without the dollar sign. Use the dollar sign if it's a variable.